# How to install and run openpose?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, computer-vision, openpose

I can't understand openpose documentation. How to install and run. I am having windows 10 laptop. Please, anyone, tell me how to use it. [CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose](https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a Quick Start for Windows user:

- Download the latest Windows build from here https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose/releases
- Unzip the build file to your Windows machine
- Run `getModels.bat` from the `models` folder to download some trained models which are not included in the build
- To process sample images come with the build, run the following command from the install folder: `bin\OpenPoseDemo.exe --image_dir examples\media\`
- You can process video with/without hand and face from files or webcam. Be careful, it will be very slow without GPU
- More info can be found here: https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose/blob/master/doc/quick_start.md#quick-start

Comment: in the documentation they have mentioned, something ".build/". Any idea what is that? because in the zip, there no such build folder.